# How to redirect to home page if user access transaction page directly

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

In my mvc web application, there are transaction pages are there like 4 steps to complete a transaction. If any user directly access one of those transaction pages, I need to redirect to Home page. How can I achieve that in MVC?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check `Request.UrlReferrer` in the controller action method of the transaction pages. If it's null, that means the page is accessed by typing the url address directly, so you need to redirect to Home page. Let's say the transaction page is `/Transaction/Step1`, here's what the controller action method will look like:

```
public ActionResult Step1()
{
    if (Request.UrlReferrer == null)
    {
        // redirect to home page here
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    else
    {
        // do something and display the transaction page
    }
}
```

Comment: It is good that, I got to know we have this option. But for my scenario, reptildarat answer will be more appropriate. Thanks you

Comment: Hey this is awsome, very generice code. I dont have to add code every where.

Answer (score 1):

Just set the sessions, when you POST the form like this (assuming you not use ajax) :

```
Public Class WizardController : Controller 
{
    public ActionResult Step1(Step1Dto data)
    {

        Session['step1'] = true;
        TempData['Step1'] = data;
        return View('Step2');
    }

    public ActionResult Step2(Step2Dto data)
    {
        if(Session['step1'] == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction('Step1');
        }
        Session['step2'] = true;

        // if you want to get the data of step1..
        // pass the action name to the TempData Method.

        var myStepData1 = TempData['Step1'];
        // set the tempdata for the step2.
        TempData['Step2'] = data;;

        return View('Step3');
    }

    // and so on...
}
```

Comment: I am passing information between the pages, using TempData. So I need to handle if the user refreshes a already loaded page( temp data will be lost for the second time). So how about that?

Comment: Just pass the Dto's into the controller then retrieve it, i will update my answer shortly.